# Run command when checking for new mail in mutt

Tags: mutt

I'd like to run a command (specifically [`imapfilter`](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter)) whenever Mutt is checking for new email, to avoid getting "wrong" messages about email in `=INBOX` which hasn't been filtered yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no facility in [mutt](http://mutt.org) to run a user-defined
command upon receiving new mail.

A workaround could be this one:

- use imapfilter itself to copy the emails to a another IMAP mailbox (e.g., `+INBOX2`),
- configure mutt to read new mail from `=INBOX2` (e.g., `set spoolfile="+INBOX2"` in `.muttrc`)

You could run `imapfilter` from mutt (just bind its invocation to a
key macro), or from a cron job.

Comment: The cron job is already in place, and I wanted specifically to avoid running it with a macro. But the idea of using a secondary inbox is great. +1 for lateral thinking.

Answer (score -2):

This might be possible by using one of the following hooks listed in [the manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.4):

- `folder-hook`
- `send-hook`
- `message-hook`
- `save-hook`
- `mbox-hook`
- `fcc-hook`
- `fcc-save-hook`

To execute an external program you may need to define a macro called from one of the hooks.

Comment: None of the hooks get called automatically when `mutt` retrieves new mail: they are all provided as a means of customizing/running commands in response to *users'* actions. (e.g., `folder-hook` is run when changing folder, `message-hook` when viewing a message, etc.)